# How to execute a CPU-bound task in background using Swift Concurrency without blocking UI updates?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-concurrency

I have an `ObservableObject` which can do a CPU-bound heavy work:

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

@MainActor
final class Controller: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var isComputing: Bool = false
    
    func compute() {
        if isComputing { return }
        
        Task {
            heavyWork()
        }
    }
    
    func heavyWork() {
        isComputing = true
        sleep(5)
        isComputing = false
    }
}
```

I use a `Task` to do the computation in background using the new concurrency features. This requires using the `@MainActor` attribute to ensure all UI updates (here tied to the `isComputing` property) are executed on the main actor.

I then have the following view which displays a counter and a button to launch the computation:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var controller: Controller
    @State private var counter: Int = 0
    
    init() {
        _controller = StateObject(wrappedValue: Controller())
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Timer: \(counter)")
            Button(controller.isComputing ? "Computing..." : "Compute") {
                controller.compute()
            }
            .disabled(controller.isComputing)
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
        .task {
            for _ in 0... {
                try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
                counter += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the computation seems to block the entire UI: the counter freezes.

**Why does the UI freeze and how to implement `.compute()` in such a way it does not block the UI updates?**

---

#### What I tried

- Making `heavyWork` and async method and scattering `await Task.yield()` every time a published property is updated seems to work but this is both cumbersome and error-prone. Also, it allows *some* UI updates but not between subsequent `Task.yield()` calls.
- Removing the `@MainActor` attribute seems to work if we ignore the purple warnings saying that UI updates should be made on the main actor (not a valid solution though).

---

#### Edit 1

Thanks to the answer proposed by @Bradley I arrived to this solution which works as expected (and is very close to the usual `DispatchQueue` way):

```swift
@MainActor
final class Controller: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var isComputing: Bool = false
    
    func compute() {
        if isComputing { return }
        
        Task.detached {
            await MainActor.run {
                self.isComputing = true
            }
            await self.heavyWork()
            await MainActor.run {
                self.isComputing = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    nonisolated func heavyWork() async {
        sleep(5)
    }
}
```

Comment: don't mark the whole class as `@MainActor`, only parts you need to run on main thread. Or move network work into a different class, that is not @MainActor. Or use `DisptachQueue.global().async` to move heavy work to background, and then `DispatchQueue.main.async` for the parts that deal with UI.

Comment: I tried it and unfortunately it does not scales well, basically need to wrap every state update in a `MainActor.run { }` which is even more boilerplate-ish than `DispatchQueue`. I thought that the `@MainActor` attribute only dispatch state update to the main actor, not entire method calls. `DispatchQueue` will certainly work but this defeat the whole purpose of using Swift Concurrency.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that `heavyWork` inherits the `MainActor` isolation from `Controller`, meaning that the work will be performed on the main thread.
This is because you have annotated `Controller` with `@MainActor` so all properties and methods on this class will, by default, inherit the `MainActor` isolation.
**But also** when you create a new `Task { }`, this inherits the current task's (i.e. the `MainActor`'s) current priority and actor isolation–forcing `heavyWork` to run on the main actor/thread.

We need to ensure (1) that we run the heavy work at a lower priority, so the system is less likely to schedule it on the UI thread.
This also needs to be a detached task, which will prevent the default inheritance that `Task { }` performs.
We can do this by using `Task.detached` with a low priority (like `.background` or `.low`).

Then (2), we ensure that the `heavyWork` is `nonisolated`, so it will not inherit the `@MainActor` context from the `Controller`.
However, this does mean that you can no longer mutate any state on the `Controller` directly.
You can still read/modify the state of the actor if you `await` accesses to read operations or `await` calls to other methods on the actor that modify the state.
In this case, you would need to make the `heavyWork` an `async` function.

Then (3), we wait for the value to be computed using the `value` property returned by the "task handle".
This allows us to access a return value from the `heavyWork` function, if any.

```swift
@MainActor
final class Controller: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var isComputing: Bool = false
    
    func compute() {
        if isComputing { return }
        Task {
            isComputing = true

            // (1) run detached at a non-UI priority
            let work = Task.detached(priority: .low) {
                self.heavyWork()
            }

            // (3) non-blocking wait for value
            let result = await work.value
            print("result on main thread", result)

            isComputing = false
        }
    }
    
    // (2) will not inherit @MainActor isolation
    nonisolated func heavyWork() -> String {
        sleep(5)
        return "result of heavy work"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, this solves the issue (I edited my question with a solution based on yours which seems to work). IMO this is too bad that there is no way to automate this (doing all work on a background actor then updating the controller state on the main thread). I thought this was the role of the `@MainActor` attribute but it seems to schedule everything on the main actor instead.

Comment: @LouisLac How do you mean automate this? In this example, the main actor is working as intended. You've told `Controller` it's main actor isolated, so everything it "does" should be on the main actor/thread. You can opt out of main actor isolation using `nonisolated` if you want or run your heavy work in a function that's located elsewhere - but it can't figure out what's "heavy" or not on its own. You will just sometimes need to use detached tasks and sometimes specify priorities for more fine-grained control over task execution.

Comment: FWIW, I need to execute everything from a class on background and only update the state that drives the UI on the main actor. E.g. an `ObservableObject` that always works in the background and updates its published properties on the main actor.

Comment: Weird, this solution does not work in my original (more complex) code but the usual GCD way works perfectly. Using Swift Concurrency I encounter a null pointer exception (which is probably due to a misuse on my side a guess).

Comment: @LouisLac A null pointer exception sounds like a Swift bug to me. See if you can isolate the issue and report to https://bugs.swift.org

Comment: I investigated it and the issue is likely on my side: probably a stack overflow due to too deep recursive call. Reducing the depth solved the issue. Thanks you for your help anyway!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I have found an alternative, using `actor hopping`.

Using the same `ContentView` as above, we can move the `heavyWork` on a standard actor:

```
@MainActor
final class Controller: ObservableObject {

  @Published private(set) var isComputing: Bool = false

  func compute() {
    
    if isComputing { return }
    
    Task {
        
        isComputing = true
        
        print("Controller isMainThread: \(Thread.isMainThread)")
        let result = await Worker().heavyWork()
        print("result on main thread", result)

        isComputing = false
    }
  }
}

actor Worker {

  func heavyWork() -> String {

    print("Worker isMainThread: \(Thread.isMainThread)")
    sleep(5)
    return "result of heavy work"
  }
}
```

The function `compute()` is called on the main thread because of the `MainActor`'s context inheritance but then, thanks to the actor hopping, the function `heavyWork()` is called on a different thread unblocking the UI.